# Is there any way to overlay a image.png on the camera preview of Flutter Image_picker library to guide the user while capturing photo?

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-image-picker, camera-overlay

I am using Flutter image_picker library in this way to click images from camera. I want the camera screen to be overlapped by a png image which contains custom wire-frame for capture guidance.

```
ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

XFile? pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

I tried different approaches but they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using the `image_picker` library as it opens the native camera of the phone.

For more flexibility, you could try [`camerawesome`](https://pub.dev/packages/camerawesome)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. Have you ever implemented Camerawesome for such kind of requirements. Where I can edit the code for this ?

Comment: @FaizanAhmed Unfortunately not. But there are a lot of examples in their readme.

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this by installing image_picker from the `pub.dev`

The only way you can achieve this is by downloading the package code from GitHub with it's dependent packages 2/3 and then, running the project locally.

After successfully running the project on the local machine, import the package directory on `pubspec.yaml`  as a local package.

Find the asset configuration where the camera opening delays the camera PNG asset is comming from. And put your capture guidance image by replacing the default Camera picture.